# How to simultaneously fit multiple correlated linear models

Tags: regression, correlation, multiple-regression, generalized-least-squares

I have two data sets labeled $\alpha$ and $\beta$, with corresponding
models that I want to fit to.
$$
\textbf{Y}_{\alpha} = \textbf{X}_{\alpha}\cdot\vec{\theta}_{\alpha} + \epsilon \\
\textbf{Y}_{\beta} = \textbf{X}_{\beta}\cdot\vec{\theta}_{\beta} + \epsilon
$$

Here the form of the design matrix $\textbf{X}$ is the same for both $\beta$ and $\alpha$. I expect $\theta_{\alpha}$ to be different from $\theta_{\beta}$. However, I know that data sets $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are highly correlated. I want to take advantage of this correlation to simultaneously determine $\theta_{\alpha}$ and $\theta_{\beta}$. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You need to give some context. What does this variables represent? In what way are they correlated? The residuals? ....

Comment: What about pooling the data and then fitting a mixed-effects model with random effects for the groups identified by data set?

Comment: To answer @kjetilbhalvorsen it is difficult to explain what the variables represent. Let's just say I am trying to apply linear models to two very similar (but different) quantities computed from Monte Carlo Simulations. Any concern about autocorrelation has already been addressed through bootstraping Monte-Carlo samples.

Comment: To answer @ulfelder, I am not sure exactly what you mean. I have never heard of a mixed-effects model. I proposed a solution below. Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have come up with a solution.

I think I can group the data in the following way

$$
\vec{\textbf{y}}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\textbf{Y}_{\alpha}\\\textbf{Y}_{\beta}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\textbf{X}_{\alpha} & 0\\ 0 & \textbf{X}_{\beta}
\end{pmatrix}\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
\theta_{\alpha} \\ \theta_{\beta}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

where 
$\vec{\textbf{y}}$ = 
$\{y_{\alpha_1}, ...,y_{\alpha_{N}}, y_{\beta_1},...,y_{\beta_M}\}$

Then my covariance matrix $\Sigma$ is an $(N+M)\times (N+M)$ matrix.

So the optimal fit parameters are

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\theta_{\alpha} \\ \theta_{\beta}
\end{pmatrix}^{\text{best}}
=
\Bigg(
\begin{pmatrix}
\textbf{X}_{\alpha} & 0\\ 0 & \textbf{X}_{\beta}
\end{pmatrix}^{\dagger}
\Sigma^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
\textbf{X}_{\alpha} & 0\\ 0 & \textbf{X}_{\beta}
\end{pmatrix}
\Bigg)^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
\textbf{X}_{\alpha} & 0\\ 0 & \textbf{X}_{\beta}
\end{pmatrix}^{\dagger}\Sigma^{-1}\vec{\textbf{y}}
$$

Constructing projection matrices to get $\theta_{\alpha}$ or $\theta_{\beta}$ are easy to see.

Comment: That assumes you know $\Sigma$ which is usually not the case. Getting an estimate of $\Sigma$ standardly involves putting restrictions on the covariance structure. So I think @kjetils question: In what way are they correlated? remains relevant. But yes Generalized Least Squares is an estimation method.